# API Architecture for a new business MI - Suitable UI?

Tags: python, rest, api-design, business-logic-layer

I have a project at work where I need to create a management information reporting dashboard that pulls data from various business applications.

I will be using REST API, as well as SQL for different systems. I was wondering if the best way to create a UI for this would be web based?

I am also learning Python and wonder if it could be a good opportunity to create a software solution to this - or is that over engineering the situation? If a web based UI will be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

What other options do you have, than going for web based UI ? But looks like, you are creating a whole new system, so a lot of the decisions depend on your specific requirements...